# How to check if it's the first time a user launches an app using is_first_run library?

Tags: flutter, dart

I tried using the is_first_run package to check if it's the first time my app has been launched. It actually worked as intended the first time I ever tested it. It took the user to the Welcome page on first launch, and then subsequent launches went to the Sign up or Log in page. But any efforts to recreate it again to make sure it's working have failed, and instead it takes me straight to Sign up or Log in, even after uninstalling the app from my device, running flutter clean, deleting all cache and storage for the app, and testing it on a completely different device. Any reason why it's not working anymore?

Here is the entire code for my main file:

```
import 'package:screens/welcomepages/signup_or_login.dart';
import 'package:screens/welcomepages/welcome.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:config/theme.dart';
import 'package:is_first_run/is_first_run.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(const SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
      statusBarBrightness: Brightness.dark));
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var ifr = _checkFirstRun();
    if (ifr == true) {
      return MaterialApp(
        theme: theme(),
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: const Welcome(),
      );
    }
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: theme(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: const SignUpOrLogIn(),
    );
  }
}

Future<bool> _checkFirstRun() async {
  return await IsFirstRun.isFirstRun();
}
```

Any alternative solutions also welcome.

Comment: You don't even need an external library, On App init check whether an expected key value pair is in the sql database of the mobile, if no. Then the user is launching it the first time, Then you can store a key value pair after it. And thus the next time, you check it will give you true or false. That is a native implementation. This will be easy to re-create if you just do flutter clean, or clean the data of the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use Shared preferences for better state management.
However, with this library, you can try the `reset()` function.

> After calling reset(), calling isFirstRun() will return true as long as the app is running. After a restart, it will return false again. The first call of isFirstCall() will return true, subsequent calls will return false again.

Comment: I've considered doing so, I will try that out since it seems to be the better solution.

Comment: I was able to solve this using Shared Preferences, thanks!